# php: get array value without iterating through it?

Tags: php, arrays

hey guys,
i think i lost my mind.

`print_r($location);` lists some geodata.

```
array (
  'geoplugin_city' => 'My City',
  'geoplugin_region' => 'My Region',
  'geoplugin_areaCode' => '0',
  'geoplugin_dmaCode' => '0',
  'geoplugin_countryCode' => 'XY',
  'geopl ...
```

when I iterate through it with a foreach loop I can print each line.
However shouldn't it be possible to just get a specific value out of the array?

like `print $location[g4];` should print the countryCode shouldn't it? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo $location['geoplugin_countryCode'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get a specific value by key. The keys in your case are the `geoplugin_` strings.

To get the country code:

```
// XY
$location['geoplugin_countryCode'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$location['geoplugin_countryCode'];
```

would access country code

Answer (score 0):

Where does "g4" come from? Did you mean "4"?

If you had a normal numerically-indexed array then, yes, you could write `$location[4]`. However, you have an associative array, so write `$location['geoplugin_countryCode']`.

Answer (score 0):

there you are using an associative array, it is an array with a user defined key:value pair (similar to dictionaries on Python and Hash Tables on C#)

You can access the elements just using the Key (in this case geoplugin_city or geoplugin_region)

Using the standard array syntax:

```
$arrayValue = $array[key];     //read
$array[key] = $newArrayValue;  //write
```

For example:

```
$location['geoplugin_city']; or $location['geoplugin_region'];
```

If you are not familiarwith PHP arrays you can take a look here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

For a better understanding on array manipulation with PHP take a look of:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php