# Return array variable in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a function and I'd like to return a variable to another function.

Can I return the array variable so I can use the variable at other function?

```
public function update_mdr_pameran() {
  //global $araydatamdr;
  $this->config->set_item('compress_output', FALSE);
  $araydatamdr['mdr_debit'] = trim($this->input->post('mdr_debit'));
  $araydatamdr['mdr_debit_npg'] = trim($this->input->post('mdr_debit_npg'));
  $araydatamdr['mdr_debit_pl'] = trim($this->input->post('mdr_debit_pl'));
  return $araydatamdr;
}
```

When I try to use `$araydatamdr` in another function, it became 0.

Am I missing something?

Comment: How do you call `$araydatamdr` at __other function__?

Comment: You don't need to `echo` and `return`. Just return it.

Comment: Echo on array doesn't work, use `var_dump($array);`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP function return array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692568/php-function-return-array)

Comment: i forget to delete it, i just try to see the value, forget the echo. sorry

Comment: `$datamdr =$araydatamdr['mdr_debit'];` its how i call the array on other function

Comment: Impossible. You should call it with something like `$arr = update_mdr_pameran()`

Comment: @Andreas so those `$arr` will be the variable i use at other function? because when i try call my function it show error _Call to undefined function update_mdr_pameran()_

Comment: https://3v4l.org/elTF8 works for me.

Comment: @Andreas what if i use it inside other function? maybe thats why i got eror undefined function?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/hbmNP nope

Comment: I think this is what everyone is missing: where is this function, and where is the other function you are trying to call this function in? Is it in the same controller or model? If so `$arr = $this->update_mdr_pameran(); print_r($arr); echo $arr['mdr_debit'];` will work. Assuming that *there is* post data, you should see some text, otherwise you will have empty values but `print_r` should still show `Array ( 'mdr_debit' => '', {.etc.})`.

Comment: @Alex its in the same controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by calling function and setting its return value to another variable.

**Method 1 :**

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();    
        }

        public function update_mdr_pameran() {
                //global $araydatamdr;
                $this->config->set_item('compress_output', FALSE);
                $araydatamdr['mdr_debit'] = trim($this->input->post('mdr_debit'));
                $araydatamdr['mdr_debit_npg'] = trim($this->input->post('mdr_debit_npg'));
                $araydatamdr['mdr_debit_pl'] = trim($this->input->post('mdr_debit_pl'));
                return $araydatamdr;
        }

        public function test_func() {
            $araydatamdr = $this->update_mdr_pameran();
            var_dump($araydatamdr);
        }

    }
```

Or you can also set $araydatamdr to $this reference.

**Method 2 :**

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {

    public $araydatamdr;
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();    
        $this->araydatamdr = [];
    }

    public function update_mdr_pameran() {
            $this->config->set_item('compress_output', FALSE);
            $this->araydatamdr['mdr_debit'] = trim($this->input->post('mdr_debit'));
            $this->araydatamdr['mdr_debit_npg'] = trim($this->input->post('mdr_debit_npg'));
            $this->araydatamdr['mdr_debit_pl'] = trim($this->input->post('mdr_debit_pl'));
    }

    public function test_func() {
        $this->update_mdr_pameran();
        var_dump($this->araydatamdr);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cross out the `echo $araydatamdr;` Arrays can be printed using `var_dump` or `print_r`. Also you can return an array in php but personally i prefer to json_encode it first so i return a json as the output of my function something like:

```
return json_encode($araydatamdr);
```

Then it's  a simple function call.

I don't know your project structure but i am giving general guidance. Apart from that i don't see anything else that could block your function.

I edit my post because i saw the issue is to call the function. There are 2 ways depending where you call it. If the function is in the same class as the other function you want to call it you simple go for :

```
$result=$this->update_mdr_pameran();
```

I see that your function has no arguments so you don't need to set any. If it's in another file:

1) include your php file at top like :

```
require 'myphpclass.php';
```

*tip make sure your path is right.

2) Create a new **class object** and then call the function like :

```
$class= new myClass();
$result=$class->update_mdr_pameran();
```

Comment: so how to get the value from those json in other function?

Comment: to see the info of a json you need also to print_r it.  If you want to treat it as an array you can json_decode it or simple you can access the json fields (that's on you). A small tip is when you decode you always use json_decode($myjson,true) to get an array and not an std class object.

Comment: actually i want to know how to use those array variable in other function

Comment: I edited my post on how to call a function. How you want to use them it's up to you. As i said above even if it's json or array it's up to you on how you treat it. But you must follow the arrays rules.